# webpack cannot resolve bootstrap module for bootstrap-loader

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

Trying to implement bootstrap-loader for webpack, but I keep running into the same issue. Tried bringing it up with the github repo devs, but no they said it works? They also recommended downgrading to bootstrap alpha 2, which did not resolve the issue.

[repo for reference](https://gitlab.com/borysn/sba2-wip/tree/master/frontend)

**error**

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader.js?configFilePath=/home/p3pt/dev/java/projects/sba2-wip/frontend/config/.bootstraprc!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js
Module build failed: Error: 
Could not find bootstrap version: '4'. Did you install it?
The package is 'bootstrap' for bootstrap v4 and 'bootstrap-sass' for v3.

    at Object.module.exports.pitch (/home/p3pt/dev/java/projects/sba2-wip/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader.js:114:11)
```

**debug log**

```
[bootstrap-loader]:  bootstrap-loader is using config file at /home/p3pt/dev/java/projects/sba2-wip/frontend/config/.bootstraprc 

[bootstrap-loader]:  Hey, we're in DEBUG mode because you have 
      your config log level set to 'debug'. 

[bootstrap-loader]:  Query from webpack config: ?configFilePath=/home/p3pt/dev/java/projects/sba2-wip/frontend/config/.bootstraprc 

[bootstrap-loader]:  Using Bootstrap module: bootstrap 

[bootstrap-loader]:  resolveModule error is  [Error: Cannot find module 'bootstrap' from '/home/p3pt/dev/java/projects/sba2-wip/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-loader/lib/utils'] 

[bootstrap-loader]:  Bootstrap module location (abs): false
```

**webpack config**

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const METADATA = webpackMerge(commonConfig.metadata, {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    ENV: ENV,
    HMR: HMR
});

const bootstrapDevEntryPoint = 'bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader?' +
          `configFilePath=${__dirname}/.bootstraprc` +
          '!bootstrap-loader/no-op.js';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    metadata: METADATA,
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    entry: {
        bootstrapDevEntryPoint
    },

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
        library: 'ac_[name]',
        libraryTarget: 'var',
    },

    plugins: [
        new DefinePlugin({
            'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
            'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
            'process.env': {
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                'HMR': METADATA.HMR
            }
        }),
    ],

    devServer: {
        port: METADATA.port,
        host: METADATA.host,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: 1000
        },
        outputPath: helpers.root('dist')
    },

    node: {
        global: 'window',
        crypto: 'empty',
        process: true,
        module: false,
        clearImmediate: false,
        setImmediate: false
    }
});
```

**package.json**

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.24",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "tether": "^1.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.33",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.1.26",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.33",
    "angular2-hmr": "~0.8.1",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "2.2.1",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.28",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "font-awesome-sass-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.4",
    "resolve": "^1.1.7",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^1.3.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0-beta",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.21",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1"
  }
...
```

Comment: I'll go ahead and ask the obvious: have you actually installed the `bootstrap`  package?

Comment: Yes, I'll post the package.json

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that bootstrap alpha 3 is broken, and the recommendation to downgrade to alpha 2 actually does work. I misunderstood that npm install would pick up on the `^` symbol and upgrade the package.

The fix revolves in changing the following in `package.json`

**change**

`"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2"`

**to**

`"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.2"`

Comment: @Necronet I'm glad this helped someone else!